# Is the "chsh" command available in Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

There is a "chsh" file in /etc/bash_completion.d . When I type "./chsh" in the directory /etc/bash_completion.d , nothing happens. Why?

If the "chsh" utility is disabled in Cygwin, are there ways to turn it on?
If it's disabled, does it imply that all the utilities in /etc/bash_completion.d are disabled in Cygwin?

Update: It seems that the "chsh" utility isn't in any package of Cygwin. Is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file in `/etc/bash_completion.d` is a library of command-line completion functions. It is not the `chsh` command.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. So the "chsh" command isn't available in Cygwin at all?

Comment: Probably not; it doesn't make much sense in a non-UNIX environment. If it's anywhere, it'll be at `/bin/chsh` or `/usr/bin/chsh`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then Cygwin only provides bash, right? There's no way to invoke another shell, e.g. tcsh?

Comment: Certainly Cygwin supports shells other than bash.  I don't think tcsh is installed by default, but it's easy enough to install it (it's under "shells" when you run setup.exe).  I don't remember whether `chsh` is available.  If not, you can run `tcsh` manually or edit `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: Yep, Cygwin also offers zsh, mksh (a Korn Shell), and a few more.

Answer (score 5):

Well answered at
http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-xfree/2010-02/msg00057.html

You need to edit /etc/passwd (with a text editor), change the last field in the line for your userid to /bin/tcsh

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the reason for chsh not being available is that Cygwin doesn't have the [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) facility for allowing an executable to be run with the rights of its owner. This would be needed to allow chsh to change the shell entry in `/etc/passwd` when run by a limited user. Administrators can edit `/etc/passwd` directly anyway.